# How can get value to PreferenceFragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="notification_settings"
        android:text="@string/impostazione"
        android:id="@+id/save_check"
        android:summary="@string/notification_title"
        android:defaultValue="false"

        ></CheckBoxPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

now i need to get Checkbox value in FragmentA:

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
```

and now?

Comment: try this way : sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notification_settings",false)

Comment: i have defaultValue, why i set again to false?

Comment: getBoolean() is required two parameter one is key another is default value.

Comment: thank you!!! i can't vote you comment, rewrite this in "Answer" and i flag :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notification_settings",false)
```

[getBoolean()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) : required two parameter one is key and another is default value

Answer (score 5):

```
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.notification_settings), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strings.xml
<string name="notification_setting">notification_settings</string>
---------------------------------
xxx.xml
.....
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="@string/notification_setting"
....
--------------------------------
.java
sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
boolean wifiState = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(R.string.setting_wifi_key, false);

wifiState is you value.
```